# The string object passed in by the method is simplified, resulting in the problem of type inference

Tags: typescript

The following text in English comes from machine translation.

I want to implement a generic type for key name renaming. At first, it works normally.

```
type PickRename<T extends {}, F extends {}> = { [K in keyof T & keyof F as F[K] extends string ? F[K] : K]: T[K] }

type A = { a: 1, b: 2 }

type B = { a: 'c' }

type C = PickRename<A, B>

type D = C['c']

type E = C['e'] // TS2339: Property 'e' does not exist on type 'C'.
```

But when I put it in the method, it can access keys that do not exist.

```
function pickRename<F extends {}>(p: F): PickRename<A, F> {
  return 0 as unknown as any
}

const b = pickRename({ a: 'c' })

b.e // Under normal circumstances, this line should report an error
```

I found that the type originally used for the `{a:' c '}` was simplified to `{a: string}` in the generic type.

[image]

This causes the return value of the method to become `{[x: string]: 1}`. Ideally, it should return `{c: 1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `as const` on the parameter:

```
const b = pickRename({ a: 'c' } as const)
```

or declare the variable `as const`

```
const obj = { a: 'c' } as const
const b = pickRename(obj)
```

and for the upcoming typescript 5.0 (still in beta at this moment), there is a new const generic type, so you can delare the function like this:

```
function pickRename<const F extends {}>(p: F): PickRename<A, F>
```